# Can't start gazebo (urdf model)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to launch gazebo using roslaunch, but somewhy I'm getting the errors.

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)
> [gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid
> 3112, exit code 139, cmd
> /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient
> __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/ulysses/.ros/log/807b3030-77a1-11e8-bd9d-08002782662e/gazebo_gui-3.log].
> log file:
> /home/ulysses/.ros/log/807b3030-77a1-11e8-bd9d-08002782662e/gazebo_gui-3*.log
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)
> [gazebo-2] process has died [pid 3107,
> exit code 139, cmd
> /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver
> -e ode /home/ulysses/catkin_ws/src/robotino_gazebo/worlds/robotino.world
> __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/ulysses/.ros/log/807b3030-77a1-11e8-bd9d-08002782662e/gazebo-2.log]. log file:
> /home/ulysses/.ros/log/807b3030-77a1-11e8-bd9d-08002782662e/gazebo-2*.log
> ^C[spawn_urdf-4] killing on exit

Here is my launch file:

> pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model"
> output="screen" args="-file $(find
> robotino_description)/urdf/robotino.urdf
> -urdf -model robotino" />

and another error:

> rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo  [ INFO]
> [1529841834.342204778]: Finished
> loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin. [ INFO]
> [1529841834.343897101]:
> waitForService: Service
> [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has
> not been advertised, waiting...
> /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gazebo:
> 46: kill: invalid signal number or
> name: SIGINT

Last time I have launched this successfully, but because of something I can't do this now. There is no gazebo-2*.log as well, but I can provide any file which can help you to help me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19817/can%27t-start-gazebo-(urdf-model)/) by [DoctorUlysses](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5409/doctorulysses/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

SOLVED: just turn off 3d acceleration in virtualbox

---

Originally posted by [DoctorUlysses](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5409/doctorulysses/) with karma: 11 on 2018-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1